# wrong output , Why is it not producing the expected output, how can I fix this error?

Tags: c

Write a program that accepts two integers, let us call them `h` and `w`, and draws a rectangle with the following specifications:

- The rectangle has height `h` and width `w`.
- The height `h` represents the number of rows (lines) the rectangle spans.
- The width `w` represents the maximum number of characters each row can have. The first and last rows will have `w` visible characters each.
- All the rows in-between will have two visible characters only, one at the beginning of the row, and the
  other at its end.
- The visible characters are either stars `*`, or hashtags `#`.
- The visible characters used in each row must alternate between rows. The first row will use stars, the second row will use hashtags, the third row will use stars, and so on.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void draw_rectangle(int h, int w) {
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == h - 1) {  // first and last rows
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                printf("*");
            }
        } else {  // rows in between
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                printf("#");
                for (int j = 0; j < w - 2; j++) {
                    printf(" ");
                }
                printf("#");
            } else {
                printf("*");
                for (int j = 0; j < w - 2; j++) {
                    printf(" ");
                }
                printf("*");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    draw_rectangle(5, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output:

```
Run1
5 10
**********
#      #
*      *
#      #
**********
Run2
7 4
****
#  #      
*  *
#  #
*  *
#  #
****
Run3
8 2
**
##
**
##
**
##
**
##
Run4
6 6
******
#   #
*   *
#   #
*   *
######
```

The current output:

```
Run1
5 10
**********
*        *
#        #
*        *
**********
Run2
7 4
****
*  *
#  #
*  *
#  #
*  *
****
Run3
8 2
**
**
##
**
##
**
##
**
Run4
6 6
******
*    *
#    #
*    *
#    #
******
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking and the expected output looks like maybe the alginment messed up a bit

Comment: This needs some debugging ..  did you try run your program step by step and try to figure out where the issue comes from ?

Comment: Pick the char to print first, based on the row number. `char c = i % 2 == 0 ? '*' : '#';` Then use `printf("%c", c);` (or `putc(c, stdout);`).

Comment: Why does the expected output use the same character for the first two rows?

Comment: Your code uses the character `*` for the first and last rows, but the current output for Run4 shows `#` on the last row. Your code does not match your current output.

Comment: The "expected output" seems to contain improper rectangles, while the "current output" contains proper ones. Did you switch them by accident?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code doesn't follow the problem requirements and so it doesn't produce the expected output:

```
void draw_rectangle(int h, int w) {
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == h - 1) {  // first and last rows

        //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                printf("*");
            }  //      ^^^

        // "The visible characters used in each row must alternate between rows.
        //  The first row will use stars, the second row will use hashtags,
        //  the third row will use stars, and so on."

        // They don't say that the last row must be printed with '*'.

        } else {  // rows in between
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
            //  ^^^^^^^^^^
                printf("#");
            //         ^^^
                for (int j = 0; j < w - 2; j++) {
                    printf(" ");
                }
                printf("#");

            // The second row would the one with index i == 1, so that
            // i % 2 == 1, while the '#' will be printed for the third row.

            } else {
                // [...]
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Note that an alternative algorithm to print the expected pattern would be

```
void draw_rectangle(int h, int w) {
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        char fill = /* '*' if i % 2 == 0 or '#' otherwise */
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            if ( /* (i,j) is on the edges of the rectangle */ )
                putchar(fill); 
            else     
                putchar(' ');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```